# Count number of values in dictionary for each key

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

I have dictionary data like the following:

```
dict = { 
'a' : ('12','3','12'), 
'b' : ('32','121'), 
'c' : ('232','9','11'), 
'd' : ('32'), 
'e' : ('243','232') 
}
```

Is that possible to count number of values for each keys?
if i use

```
sum(len(v) for v in dict[j].itervalues())
```

it returns counts of all values ...in above case it return 11
but i need for specific key... for example for key 'c' gives 3 (number of values it has).
so is there any a method to do it...
thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new_dict = {k: len(v) for k,v in dict.items()}
```