# counting the number of values in a specific key for a python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, count, tuples

Can someone explain this to me, and/or direct me on the right/pythonic way of doing this?

Python 2.7.

Ultimately, I am trying to loop through dictionary countsD:

```
countsD = {"aa": None, "bb": None, "cc": None, "dd": None}
```

and for the match in a corresponding dictionary d:

```
d = {"aa": (5689, 34, 44, 77, 88, 321), "bb": (33, 6742, 89744), "cc": (45, 98), "dd": (1, 33)}
```

add the count of items as a value to the corresponding matching key, to create finally this countsD

```
{"aa": 6, "bb": 3, "cc": 2, "dd": 2}
```

If I do this with the above

```
> d = {"aa": (5689, 34, 44, 77, 88, 321), "bb": (33, 6742, 89744), "cc": (45, 98), "dd": (1, 33)}

> for key in d:

>>     print(key)
>>     print(len(d[key]))
```

Returned is this, which is what I want

```
aa
6
cc
2
dd
2
bb
3
```

HOWEVER, if one of the values for a key only contains 1 value (entirely possible), like (see "cc"):

```
d = {"aa": (5689, 34, 44, 77, 88, 321), "bb": (33, 6742, 89744), "cc": (45), "dd": (1, 33)}
```

and then run the same for loop, I get an error on the "cc" key:

```
aa
6
cc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

HOWEVER again, if I make that "cc" key have an empty value (), then all is fine again.

```
d = {"aa": (5689, 34, 44, 77, 88, 321), "bb": (33, 6742, 89744), "cc": (), "dd": (1, 33)}

>>> d = {"aa": (5689, 34, 44, 77, 88, 321), "bb": (33, 6742, 89744), "cc": (), "dd": (1, 33)}
>>> for key in d:
...     print(key)
...     print(len(d[key]))
... 
aa
6
cc
0
dd
2
bb
3
```

And in typing the title for this post just now, I was referred to [Count number of values in dictionary for each key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865851/count-number-of-values-in-dictionary-for-each-key) for an answer.  Great, one line!  But again, for a key with just one value, it fails.  This good:

```
>>> d = {"aa": (5689, 34, 44, 77, 88, 321), "bb": (33, 6742, 89744), "cc": (), "dd": (1, 33)}
>>> new_countsD = {k: len(v) for k,v in d.items()}
>>> new_countsD
{'aa': 6, 'bb': 3, 'cc': 0, 'dd': 2}
```

this not, see key "cc"

```
>>> d = {"aa": (5689, 34, 44, 77, 88, 321), "bb": (33, 6742, 89744), "cc": (111), "dd": (1, 33)}
>>> new_countsD = {k: len(v) for k,v in d.items()}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <dictcomp>
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

So, what gives??  I feel like I am missing something stupid...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a tuple with only one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876177/how-to-create-a-tuple-with-only-one-element)

Comment: True.  Sometimes, especially when you're new to this, you just don't exactly know what to search for to figure it  out yourslef.  Ultimately, I did not know that what I was dealing here was a tuple.  But, all these responses were helpful, good learning for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because when you save a value like `cc` with only one value, it is just saved as an `int` and is no longer a tuple, which means it does not have a `len()` function. You can just add a check of the value's `type`, such as:

```
if type(d[key]) == int:
    print(1)
else:
    print(len(d[key]))
```

This way, you will not try to access the length property of an `int`, and will not get your error.

Comment: Thank-you for the help!!  But I must say that seems odd that you can't get a length of 1 for one item, but you can get a length/count of zero for no items.... in a tuple.  I'm not a pro at this, so not for me to understand yet :-D

Comment: So how would you implement this test for int vs tuple with  'new_countsD = {k: len(v) for k,v in d.items()}'  ???

Answer (score 4):

In python, a single-item tuple (called a singleton) is written as `(value,)`, so the `(111)` in your input should be written as `(111,)` instead; otherwise it would be considered an integer of `111`.

From [`tuple`'s documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences):

> A special problem is the construction of tuples containing 0 or 1
>   items: the syntax has some extra quirks to accommodate these. Empty
>   tuples are constructed by an empty pair of parentheses; a tuple with
>   one item is constructed by following a value with a comma (it is not
>   sufficient to enclose a single value in parentheses). Ugly, but
>   effective.
>
> ```
> >>> empty = ()
> >>> singleton = 'hello',    # <-- note trailing comma
> >>> len(empty)
> 0
> >>> len(singleton)
> 1
> >>> singleton
> ('hello',)
> ```

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark this question as answered if you think it's correct?